# External interrupts to MCU from ADV7511

Tags: microcontroller, connector, embedded, interrupts, hdmi

I am having situation that when I connect my monitor with [ADV7511](http://www.analog.com/en/products/audio-video/hdmidvi-transmitters/adv7511.html), it triggers interrupt (when hot plug detect happens) but more than one time, so I done debouncing. Problem is when I am unplugging cable, I don't know if I can call it bouncing, as it causes also multiple interrupts during pulling the cable out of the connector.

How to solve that problem? Does it also need some kind of debouncing? But it lasts more than second or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what this "ADV7511" is or how it's even relevant.  In any case, mechanical connections bounce.  This happens both on make and on break.

If the bouncing matters to you application, then debounce the signal.  That really should be obvious.

How long you debounce for depends on how long the connection bounces for, and how long it is acceptable to wait before reacting to the new condition.  It seems the action you want to detect is a monitor being plugged and unplugged to/from a computer.  It seems like a few seconds delay would be acceptable, but that's really something you have to decide.